# How to get Dropdownlist value on HTML Table

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I have an editable table, whatever we change it is updated in the database.
I want something like a select option from the dropdown list and it should be added in the table cell

[image]

[image: I want something like this]

I want something Like this.
When we select an option from dropdown it should be set as td(cell) value

Comment: Now we know what you want, now we want to know, what have you done so far to achieve what you want?

Comment: I added select box in td and use javascript to get value. BUt instead of saving single value in database, It is saving all values from selectbox.

I Want to know
1) How can I get select box selected value in td

Comment: Please show the code, we can't fix a code we can't see.

Comment: Hi Teemu, I achieve this finally by using below code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieve this by using javascript.

```js
<script>
$('select').change(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.parent().siblings('td[id^=row-]').html($this.val());
});
</script>
```

```html
<table><tr><td> <select id="select1">
      <option value="$">--Please Select--</option>
      <option value="val1">value 1</option>
      <option value="val2">value 2</option>
      <option value="val3">value 3</option>
</select></td>

<td  id="row-1"></td></tr></table>
```